# Trigger event on clearing text field : Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text field where I call a function on `onkeypress` like this

```
<input type="textbox" class="txtbox" id="userid" onkeypress="keyPress()" >
```

I am trying to handle the event when the text field is completely cleared. I tried this but doesn't seem to work

```
function keyPress()
{
    if(document.getElementById('userid').value == null)
    { alert();}
}
```

Is there a better/correct way to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: `input type="text"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking empty string (`""`) instead of `null`.

```
if(el.value == "" || el.value.trim() == ""){
```

**Please Note:** You can pass `this.value` to the function so that you can use that inside the function. I will also prefer `oninput` instead of `onkeypress`.

```js
function keyPress(elVal){
  if(elVal == "" || elVal.trim() == ""){
    alert("Empty");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="textbox" class="txtbox" id="userid" oninput="keyPress(this.value)" >
```

Comment: this works but when I pass `this.value` it returns the previous value not the current `null` value

Comment: @RedBottle, I think passing `this.value` works the same way. Also notice the use of `.trim()` as the second condition, this will work for empty space also. Please check the updated answer.....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to change `el.value.trim()` to `el.trim()` though @Mamun

Answer (score 5):

You can use `onkeyup` instead and compare it to empty string instead of `null`, consider the following:

```js
function keyUp(val) {
  if (val == "") {
    alert();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="textbox" class="txtbox" id="userid" onkeyup="keyUp(this.value)">
```